# Como desabilitar um campo input após dar um tique em um checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, pessoal, gostaria de saber como faço para habilitar / desabilitar um campo input após o usuário selecionar uma opção em um ´checkbox´?

Meu formulário tem uma pergunta e, se o usuário selecionar o checkbox "Não", gostaria de desabilitar o campo seguinte:

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li>
      <div>
         <label>Possui Dependentes?</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkDependentesSim" name="Dependentes[1][]"> Sim
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkDependentesNao" name="Dependentes[1][]"> Não
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <!-- Quero que o input nessa div fique habilitado caso o usuário selecione "Sim",
      senão, fica 'disabled' -->
      <div>
         <label>Quantidade de Dependentes</label>
         <input type="text" required style="border: solid 0.5px #000; width: 300px; height: 37px;">
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Já tenho um JS que desmarca uma opção caso o usuário escolha a outra (desmarca "Sim" se o usuário clica "Não", e vice-versa):

```
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
   var $box = $(this);
   if ($box.is(":checked")) {
      var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
      $(group).prop("checked", false);
      $box.prop("checked", true);
   } else {
      $box.prop("checked", false);
   }
});
```

Preciso de uma função JS que verifique, quando o usuário clicar no ´checkbox´, se o próximo campo será desabilitado ou não.

Comment: Qual seu nivel de conhecimento em javascript, Renan?

Comment: Básico, cara... Posso dizer que sou iniciante, no máximo, indo pra intermediário. Mas iniciante ainda! Hehe

Comment: Para começar acredito que o principio está errado, o que você precisa é de um input:radio, não input:checkbox. O radio já vem com essa opção de um desmarcar o outro.

Comment: Tudo bem, é uma boa sugestão... Mas ainda assim, eu precisaria de uma função para habilitar / desabilitar o campo seguinte, certo?

Comment: Importante [edit] e deixar bem clara a parte que tem a dificuldade (o que tentou, e o que saiu diferente do esperado). Reduzir o código a um [mcve] ajuda bastante.

Comment: Alguém bloqueou o sistema de respota para essa pergunta então vou te ajudar pelos comentários.

Comment: Poxa, que pena... Não me dou bem nesse site. :(

Comment: O que você precisa fazer é colocar ou remover o atributo disblaed ou readonly no campo, assim:
$('#idQtdDependentes').attr('disabled','disabled'); Automáticamnet não dará mais para editar o campo.

Comment: Eu estava formulando uma resposta. É dúvida de iniciante, ele tem que usar um `radio` no lugar do `checkbox`, criar um *css* com com essa classe`.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.4;
}` e no *JS* dependendo do valor do `radio` usar [addClass("disabled")](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/) ou [removeClass("disabled")](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Comment: O Augusto deu uma boa sugestão também.

Comment: @Renan deixe o código em javascript mais limpo, e tire os comentários em inglês, que a será reaberta.

Comment: tirei os comentários, @AugustoVasques, valeu! E se eu usar radio com o estilo do checkbox, tem como? E como verifico o valor do radio no JS? Seria algo mais ou menos assim: var checkBoxSim = document.getElementById("checkSim");
if (checkBoxSim.checked === true) {
    // blablabla
}
?

Comment: Embora eu não ache que essa seja uma pergunta lá muito boa, ainda acho que ela é respondível e válida. Votei pela reabertura.

Comment: Eu crie um exemplo [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/cbcarlos/1dv9bogu/2/) pra você dá uma olhada se é mais ou menos isso

Comment: Já que você vai usar sim ou não, por que não usa apenas um checkbox, para caso estiver marcado é sim e desmarcado não?

Comment: Obrigado, pessoal, consegui resolver usando uma função mais simples... Mesmo assim, obrigado a todos pela ajuda!